# is there any side effect of creating multiple database files for a single android application?

Tags: android, sqlite

is there any side effect of creating multiple database files for a single android application ?

why do i need to do this ?

Because i am creating an application which uses a common module used in multiple other projects.

that common module has his own DB file lets call it "core.db" which contain some tables for example [table1, table2], and my application need to have more tables to run correctly for example [table 3 , table 4].

Comment: can you explain this a bit more..? Actually there is no problem for you to have as much databases as you want to have in your application..  But for that there should be a reason as well

Comment: I have already mentioned that in the question body , we already have a module that i cant touch its DB files and i want to add more tables , if for my new project i created a new DB helper class and named the DB the same name as the core does [core.db] my application will not work any more

Comment: **"...i cant touch its DB files... "** : Why not? Your common module won't even know anything about any new tables that your app adds to it's DB. Your app will know about the original tables and the ones that have been added but the common module will only know about the original tables.

Comment: ok.. i got it.. the question here is does this databases keep same data (here i mean same structures, same type of data).. Cause if they don't i think it is the only reasonable solution to make separate database for new app. That is not a problem. In case they do have same data, than it will get messy after some time of development cause you will have if/else all over project to decide which database should u use. In that case it would be bad architectural decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing an application from having multiple database files, nor from accessing more than one database file at a time.

Absent any other information, my only caution is about having multiple instances of a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class attempting to access the same database, as that can result in database lock contention. (This applies even if you only had one database file.)

Comment: thanks for the answer and mentioning the lock contention

Answer (score 0):

I Think your application could become larger and use more memory and load slower